# Application tried to present modally a view controller <StartViewController: 0x14e90bfb0> that has a parent view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

Loading up a (very) old objective-c project, to do some bug fixes and it crashes out before I have gotten the chance to even load it to test, the line it crashes on is indicated below;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     
    activeViewController = [self loadStartViewController];     
    [self.view addSubview:activeViewController.view]; //Crashing on this line
    [activeViewController viewDidAppear:NO];
   
}
```

the `loadStartViewController` method is;

```
- (UIViewController*) loadStartViewController {
    StartViewController *viewController = [StartViewController alloc];
    return viewController;
}
```

Appreciate this will likely need far further fixing, but wanted to get at least into the app first.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you're allocating an instance of `StartViewController` but you're not initializing it.

Second, assuming you have code inside `StartViewController` you want to add it as a child view controller.

Third, never call methods such as `viewDidAppear`

So, really quick example...

---

**SomeViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

---

**SomeViewController.m**

```
#import "SomeViewController.h"
#import "StartViewController.h"

@interface SomeViewController ()
@end

@implementation SomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBlueColor];
    
    StartViewController *vc = [StartViewController new];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
    
    // let's give it a frame so we can see it's been added
    vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(40, 100, 240, 320);
    
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    
}

@end
```

---

**StartViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface StartViewController : UIViewController
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

---

**StartViewController.m**

```
#import "StartViewController.h"

@interface StartViewController ()
@end

@implementation StartViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemYellowColor];
    
    UILabel *v = [UILabel new];
    v.text = @"Start VC";
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:v];
    [v.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor].active = YES;
    [v.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerYAnchor].active = YES;

}

@end
```

Looks like this:

[image]